# How to dynamically set the width of a div according to the screensize?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, styled-components

I have a web application where I would like to dynamically change the width of a div according to the screen size, just like this application does: https://gyazo.com/ce99185a58e5c7d8cef9f8375952db8c

Ideally I would love to know how I could achieve this on my own. Any information would be greatly appreciated. This is how I tried to do it, but it does not work:

The application is divided into two equal segments, left and right.

I am using `vue-styled-components` to set css properties with javascript.

```
import styled from "vue-styled-components";

let widthProps = { dynamicWidth: String }

const RightContent = styled('div', widthProps)`
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
    width: ${props => props.dynamicWidth};
    max-height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 32px;
    padding-right: 48px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    padding-left: 48px;
`;

export default RightContent;
```

I thought I could dynamically set the divs `width` with something like this:

```
<RightContent id="rightContent" :dynamicWidth="dynamicWidth">
```

```
onResize() {
  window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    let rightcontent = window.document.getElementById("rightContent");
    if (rightcontent) {
      //the 96 is padding left and padding right
      let width = rightcontent.offsetWidth - 96;
      console.log(width);
      this.valueIWantToSetTheWidthOfTheDivTo = width;
      // this.dynamicWidth = `${width}px`;
    }
  });
}
```

I would call this function in the `created()` hook.

However, once I uncomment this line: `` // this.dynamicWidth = `${width}px`; ``, the width gets set and is static, so it will always be the value it was when the screen got resized the first time.

I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-fire-fhwyf?file=/src/components/Right.vue:585-1019) with my problem.

Comment: To get started with responsive, try using media queries. [Here is a link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: I don't want to use media queries. Those don't fit my use case.

Comment: Your code is not working because of you always read the width you set. Since you set the width via style attribute the default behavior of css grid had overridden.

Comment: How could I do it differently so that it works like in the gif? @User28

Comment: You may try to read the width of its parent instead or just `window.innerWidth`.

Comment: That worked surprisingly well @User28, managed to do it :). Thank you.